# setting user.dir for gradle app running in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle, buildship

I have a gradle app a former employee developed that runs perfectly from the command line using ./gradlew.  But now I'm trying to debug it in eclipse, so I'm starting by just trying to run it in eclipse.

I have the Buildship Gradle plugin installed and have created a run configuration that specified the working directory and passes program arguments.  WHenever it tries to access anything in the filesystem, it's using the wrong path when the app uses System.getProperty("user.dir") - which is defaulting to my user's home directory instead of the project folder.

I've tried adding a "GRADLE_USER_HOME" classpath variable, but it doesn't seem to change anything.  I've also tried setting Gradle User Home (under Preferences - Gradle) to the project folder, but that too doesn't help.  I've also tried changing the Gradle Distribution from "From Import Settings" to "Gradle Wrapper", but that doesn't help.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you please reformat the question to be more 'readable'?

Comment: I also ran into this using `ProcessBuilder` from gradle. I tried getting the current dir with `new ProcessBuilder().directory()`, `Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath()`, and `System.getProperty("user.dir")`, both from Eclipse and the command line. In both cases ProcessBuilder returns null, which means it uses user.dir. In both cases Paths returns my project directory, which is what I wanted. But user.dir is the project directory when run from the command line and my home dir when run in Eclipse. I don't know if it's "right", but it breaks my gradle build.

Answer (score 0):

The system property `user.dir` has nothing to do with Gradle and I bet that it is also not set in the Gradle scripts. The system property `user.dir` is the current working directory of the user when he starts the program. So if you are in your project directory and call `./gradlew run`, the working directory is your project directory. If you go one level up and call `<project>/gradlew run` you will also see a different behavior like from eclipse.

Set the working directory for the run configuration to your project directory, then you should get the right behavior. And probably you should fix this, so that not `user.dir` is used, if the project depends on the path being the project directory.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I had already put the project path into the working directory of the gradle run configuration.  Should I be using some other variable in order to get that path from the project instead of using user.dir?  When I output the value of user.dir, I see that it is just my home directory and not the project directory.

Comment: I can only guess that you have setup the Eclipse run configuration wrongly if `user.dir` is not what you have set up as working directory. I greatly dislike Eclipse and prevent using it where I can, so I can hardly guess what you maybe did wrongly. No there is no system property to get the project directory. You need to implement some clever logic by determining where the classes are present during runtime or similar.